# PHP: filter_input com REQUEST

Tags: php, validação

Como a maioria deve saber, no PHP 5.2 foi implementada a função `filter_input`.

Estou trabalhando tranquilo com ela, sem nenhuma dúvida muito alarmante.

O problema é que: eu consigo trabalhar bem com ela, utilizando no 1º parâmetro as flags `INPUT_GET` ou `INPUT_POST` quando preciso validar utilizando o `FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED`.

Porém, na aplicação que estou trabalhando também preciso validar o `INPUT_REQUEST` (que não está implementado), e aí vem o erro.

[image: Erro PHP filter_input 'INPUT_REQUEST']

**Detalhe que a versão do PHP que estou utilizando é a 5.5.6.**

Gostaria de saber se alguém conhece ou tem algum método que faça o filtro do `$_REQUEST` assim como o filter_input deveria fazer.

Comment: Posta a parte do código que está dando erro.

Answer (score 3):

A variável `$_REQUEST` é uma supervariável que contém as variávels `$_GET`, `$_POST` e `$_COOKIE`, na ordem definida pela diretiva `request_order` do PHP.

Sendo assim, não vejo a necessidade de usar a constante `INPUT_REQUEST` se você souber de qual das outras supervariáveis o valor que você quer filtrar está vindo.

Comment: A questão é que às vezes, em parte do código, eu faço uma chamada via ajax pra uma página `query.php?key1=val1&key2=val2` e ainda passo parâmetros POST, ou seja, ela recebe GET e POST, logo, seria mais rápido tratar o request.

Comment: Não sei onde li que usar a variável `$_REQUEST` constitui uma falha de segurança, pois a variável pode vir de três maneiras diferentes. Além disso, se você usa `$_GET`, `$_POST` ou `$_COOKIE`, você está sendo explícito no seu código de onde a variável está vindo. Pessoalmente, não vejo problema em optar por um desses em vez do `$_REQUEST` :)

Comment: Também tava sabendo dessa falha de segurança pelo `REQUEST` mas resolvi tentar assim mesmo, e desisti. Fiz uma função bem simples pra tratar isso: `switch ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) {
        case 'GET':
            return filter_input(INPUT_GET, $val, FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
        default:
        case 'POST':
            return filter_input(INPUT_POST, $val, FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

Esse é um tópico bastante antigo, mas já que este foi trazido à tona novamente deixarei duas possíveis soluções para o problema.

Como você bem descobriu, a funcionalidade de INPUT_REQUEST não foi implementada, então diferentemente do sugerido pelo Marcio, você **não pode** utilizar [filter_input_array()](http://www.php.net/filter_input_array) pois terá o mesmo erro.

A primeira solução apoia-se na função [filter_var_array()](http://www.php.net/filter_var_array). Sua aplicabilidade é mais apropriada quando:

- Todas as entradas puderem receber o mesmo tipo de tratamento
- Você não souber o que pode vir por **$_REQUEST**

Para usar [função filter_var_array()](http://www.php.net/filter_var_array) você deve criar um array associativo tendo como chaves os índices presentes em $_REQUEST (ou em outro array que precise) e como valores os filtros a serem aplicados.

Mas, como precisamos do memso dinamismo proporcionado por pela *flag* que usaríamos em [filter_input()](http://www.php.net/filter_input) e [filter_input_array()](http://www.php.net/filter_input_array), não podemos criar esse array manualmente, então usaremos [array_combine()](http://www.php.net/array_combine), [array_keys()](http://www.php.net/array_keys) e [array_fill()](http://www.php.net/array_fill) que, juntos, permitirão a criação de um novo array em *runtime*, de comprimento variável e com a mesma estrutura de $_REQUEST:

```
$args = array_combine(

    array_keys( $_REQUEST ),

    array_fill( 0, count( $_REQUEST ), FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED )
);
```

[array_combine()](http://www.php.net/array_combine) espera dois arrays como argumento. Um para servir de chaves e outro de valores.

Usamos [array_keys()](http://www.php.net/array_keys) para obter todas as chaves de $_REQUEST e, como não sabemos quantos elementos existem em $_REQUEST para podermos montar a contra-parte necessária, usamos [array_fill()](http://www.php.net/array_fill) que cria um novo array com uma quantidade pré-definida de elementos, aqui obtidos [contando](http://www.php.net/count) a quantidade de entradas em $_REQUEST. Todas as entradas terão o mesmo valor, no caso, a *flag* FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED.

E passaremos esse array para [filter_var_array()](http://www.php.net/filter_var_array):

```
$filtered = filter_var_array( $_REQUEST, $args );
```

Isso num arquivo acessado com uma URL propositalmente nociva como `http://localhost:8080/test.php?foo=<script>alert('hi');</script>`, resulta um var_dump() com:

```
array (size=1)
  'foo' => string '%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27hi%27%29%3B%3C%2Fscript%3E' (length=49)
```

A segunda alternativa é iterar o array desejado ($_REQUEST) e aplicar [filter_var()](http://www.php.net/filter_var) em cada entrada gerando um novo array limpo.

Ela é mais apropriada quando:

- Algumas entradas não puderem ser validadas por uma *flag* em particular -OU- requerer uma *flag* específica que não justificaria aplicar aos outros valores
- O array a ser filtrado/validado/sanitizado é pequeno, porque iterar arrays grandes é ruim para performance

  ```
   $cleansed = array();

   foreach( $_REQUEST as $offset => $entry ) {
       $cleansed[ $offset ] = filter_var( $entry, FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED );
   }
  ```

A saída desse array será a mesma acima.

Quanto à primeira consideração de aplicabilidade feita sobre essa segunda técnica, você não necessariamente precisa levar ela em consideração para optar por essa técnica.

Você pode muito bem usar o primeiro método e, logo em após criar o array a ser usado (**$args**), sobrescrever um ou mais índices previamente conhecidos manualmente antes de informar esse array como argumento para [filter_var_array()](http://www.php.net/filter_var_array):

```
$args = array_combine(

    array_keys( $_REQUEST ),

    array_fill( 0, count( $_REQUEST ), FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED )
);

$args['algum_campo_de_URL'] = FILTER_SANITIZE_URL;

// Ou

$args['algum_campo_sem_tratamento'] = NULL;
```

> Nota: Não remova o índice com [unset()](http://www.php.net/unset) caso contrário a entrada correspondente. ao invés de ser mantida intocada, será removida do array resultante.

---

Agora que o problema foi solucionado em gostaria de deixar uma palavrinha sobre o porquê de usar $_REQUEST poder ser prejudicial.

Os chamados [HTTP Verbs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html) foram criados em sua vasta especificidade para servir cada um para um propósito único. E apesar de atualmente nenhum browser respeitar todos os verbos quando definidos no atributo **method** de um formulário, não significa que você deva programar de forma errada também.

Sendo assim, se é POST, usemos $_POST. Se é GET, usemos $_GET. Precisamos de algum cookie? $_COOKIES.

Agora veja um cenário hipotético onde usar $_REQUEST ao invés de um dos três superglobais corretos é prejudicial:

Imagina uma situação na qual você coincidentemente tem uma variável de nome X que DEVE transitar exclusivamente via GET e outra, também chamada X, exclusivamente por POST.

Usando $_GET e $_POST, você pode perfeitamente utilizar os nomes idênticos. Mesmo que não pareça muito certo, às vezes, por harmonia léxica (sou tarado por isso com programo :P), é justificável.

Mas se você codificar seu script inteiramente com $_REQUEST, um sobrescreverá o outro e pela sutileza do procedimento, o debug seria complicado.

Veja um exemplo (bem porco) ilustrando isso:

```
var_dump( $_REQUEST, $_POST, $_GET );

echo '<form method="post">';
echo '<input type="hidden" name="nome" value="Bruno" />';
echo '<input type="submit" value="Vai" />';

echo '</form>';
```

Ao acessar a página pela primeira vez haverão três arrays vazios, afinal não existe informação ainda.

Colocando um parâmetro GET **nome** na URL (Bruno Augusto, para ilustrar), você verá **Bruno Augusto** saindo de $_REQUEST e outro, no terceiro, de $_GET. O segundo, referente à $_POST, continuará vazio.

Submeta o formulário. Será mostrado Bruno **duas vezes** e **Bruno Augusto** uma.

Isso porque o $_REQUEST mescla tudo e, graças à [ordem das variáveis](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order), o **Bruno** do campo oculto vindo de $_POST sobrescreverá o **Bruno Augusto** vindo de $_GET, porque nos arrays superglobais, possuem o mesmo índice.

Você também é afetado por esse problema bastante sutil ao usar JavaScript pois dados GET e POST são basicamente cabeçalhos e também estão sujeitos a sobrescrita.

Ainda não está convencido quanto ao seu caso por transitar dados por AJAX? Tá bom:

**test.html**

```
$(function(){

    $.ajax({

        method: 'post', 
        url: 'http://localhost/test.php?var1=value1',
        data: { var1: 'some content', var2: 'doh' }

    }).done( function( data ) {

        console.log( data );

    }).fail( function( xhr, status ) {

        console.log( status );
    });

});
```

**test.php**

O console response após a Requisição de sucesso:

```
"{"var1":"value1"}

{"var1":"some content","var2":"doh"}

{"var1":"some content","var2":"doh"}"
```

**var1** em $_REQUEST por padrão preenchida com **var1** de $_GET foi sobrescrita pelo **var1** vindo de $_POST.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode tentar utilizar [filter_input_array()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.filter-input-array.php). Por exemplo:

```
$vars = array(
    'key1' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT
);

$entradas = filter_input_array(INPUT_REQUEST, $vars);

echo $entradas['key1'];
```

Outra opção é utilizar [filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php), o uso é simples:

```
echo filter_var($_REQUEST['key1'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

Mas lembre-se que os filtros estão longe de garantir que sua aplicação está segura, você deve procurar parametrizar suas querys via [PDO](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.pdo.php) e escapar caracteres especiais de acordo com o seu banco de dados.